# Listview.offsetTopAndBottom won't persist in Android

Tags: java, android, listview

When the ImageView is dragged, I want both the ImageView and ListView to move vertically and stay there. Below is my code. At first, it seemed to work, but when I scroll up and down the listview, the listview jumps back to where it originally was. Can someone tell me how to fix this problem?

```
class MyOnGestureListener implements OnGestureListener{

  public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                float distanceX, float distanceY) {

  mImageView.scrollBy(0, (int)distanceY);
  mListView.offsetTopAndBottom((int)-distanceY);
  mListView.invalidate();
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to override onLayout and persist it there. The base ViewGroup (ListView) will recalculate positioning there and override your offset. Which means, in your case, you'll need to extend ListView to override it.

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    final int offset = getMenuState() != MenuState.Closed ? getContentView().getLeft() : 0;

    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

    /*
     * Lazily offset the view - rather than comparing the child views to find the
     * content view
     */
    getContentView().offsetLeftAndRight(offset);
}
```